# Create a vector of sequences with varying "by" arguments

Tags: r, vector

I'm interested in creating a vector of sequences, all from 0 to 1, but with varying "by" arguments to seq( ).

I start with a vector I'm hoping to use for the "by" argument:

```
x <- c(3,6,3,9,10)
```

I'm wanting this to be the input to the seq( ) function:

```
seq(0, 1, by = 1/(x-1))
```

So for the first few elements of the vector it would be:

```
seq(0, 1, by = 1 / (3 - 1))
seq(0, 1, by = 1 / (6 -1))
```

Yielding vectors like:

```
0.0 0.5 1.0
0.0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0
```

Ultimately, I'd like the output to be a long vector that includes all of these sequences of varying lengths.  Maybe a job for a loop?  Or sapply / lapply?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need a loop, as `seq` only generates equally-spaced values.  But it's a simple loop: `myseq<-vector(); for(i in 1:length(x)) myseq<-c(myseq,seq(0,1,by=1/(x[j]-1)))`  (Not tested)

Answer (score 4):

```
sapply(1/(x-1), seq, from=0, to=1)

[[1]]
[1] 0.0 0.5 1.0

[[2]]
[1] 0.0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0

[[3]]
[1] 0.0 0.5 1.0

[[4]]
[1] 0.000 0.125 0.250 0.375 0.500 0.625 0.750 0.875 1.000

[[5]]
 [1] 0.0000 0.1111 0.2222 0.3333 0.4444 0.5556 0.6667 0.7778 0.8889 1.0000
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way: I use `seq.default` since you need to vectorize the `by` argument

```
x <- c(3,6,3,9,10)

vseq <- Vectorize(seq.default)

vseq(0, 1, by = 1/(x-1))

# [[1]]
# [1] 0.0 0.5 1.0
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 0.0 0.5 1.0
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 0.000 0.125 0.250 0.375 0.500 0.625 0.750 0.875 1.000
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 0.0000000 0.1111111 0.2222222 0.3333333 0.4444444 0.5555556 0.6666667 0.7777778
# [9] 0.8888889 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the code would be for an example x = 1000

```
vector_x <- c()
for(i in 1:1000){

  x <- seq(0, 1, by = 1/(i-1))
  vector_x <- c(vector_x, x)

}

vector_x
```